# how to program this indicator script to work with stocks and not just futures

Tags: indicator, trading

i found this.. posted it in the Amibroker editor.. saved.. found out after looking into it further.. that it will only work on futures that are listed in the if statements within the code.. i'd like to see this for stocks.. any ideas..

```
// ACD Plot
// LSMA is Linreg
// ACD.afl
// v 1.2 9/13/2004

SetChartBkColor(16);

Per = Param("Periods",13);
Per2 = Param("Periods 2",34);
LSMAPer = Param("LMSA Period",25);
Offset = Param("A Level",1);
ACDFlag = 0;
IntervalFlag = IIf(Interval(format=0)==300,1,0);

strInterval = Interval(format=2);

strWeekday = StrMid("SunMonTueWedThuFriSat", SelectedValue(DayOfWeek())*3,3);


if( StrFind( Name(), "YM" ) )
{
    ACDOffset = 10;
    ACDFlag = 1;
    ACDTime = 94500;
}

if( StrFind( Name(), "ER" ) )
{
    ACDOffset = 0.5;
    ACDFlag = 1;
    ACDTime = 93500;
}

if( StrFind( Name(), "ES" ) )
{
    ACDOffset = 2;
    ACDFlag = 1;
    ACDTime = 94500;
}

if( StrFind( Name(), "NQ" ) )
{
    ACDOffset = 3;
    ACDFlag = 1;
    ACDTime = 94500;
}

if( StrFind( Name(), "ZB" ) )
{
    ACDOffset = 0.15;
    ACDFlag = 1;
    ACDTime = 83000;
}

if( StrFind( Name(), "ZN" ) )
{
    ACDOffset = 0.15;
    ACDFlag = 1;
    ACDTime = 83000;
}

GraphXSpace = 1;
Shift = 2;

// calculate the pivot range
PDH = TimeFrameGetPrice( "H", inDaily, -1 ); // gives previous Day High when working on intraday data
PDL = TimeFrameGetPrice( "L", inDaily, -1 );
PDC = TimeFrameGetPrice( "C", inDaily, -1 );
PP = (PDH+PDL+PDC)/3;

DIFF = abs((PDH+PDL)/2 - PP);
PRHi = PP + DIFF;
PRLo = PP - DIFF;

EMA1 = EMA(Avg,Per);
EMA2 = EMA(Avg,Per2);
LSMA = LinearReg(Avg, LSMAPer);

Plot(C, "Close",colorWhite,styleCandle);


if (ACDFlag AND IntervalFlag) {
    ORHigh= ValueWhen(TimeNum()<ACDTime,HighestSince(DateNum()>Ref(DateNum(),-1),High));
    ORLow = ValueWhen(TimeNum()<ACDTime,LowestSince(DateNum()>Ref(DateNum(),-1), Low));

    Plot(PRHi,"PRHigh",colorWhite,styleDots+styleNoLine+styleNoLabel);
    Plot(PRLo,"PRLow",colorWhite,styleDots+styleNoLine+styleNoLabel);
    Plot(ORHigh,"ORHigh",colorBlue,style=styleStaircase+styleDots+styleNoLine+styleNoLabel);
    Plot(ORLow,"ORLow",colorBlue,style=styleStaircase+styleDots+styleNoLine+styleNoLabel);
    Plot(ORHigh+ACDOffset,"AUp",colorYellow,style=styleStaircase+styleDots+styleNoLine);
    Plot(ORLow-ACDOffset,"ADn",colorYellow,style=styleStaircase+styleDots+styleNoLine);
    // Plot(LSMA, "LSMA", colorYellow,style=styleThick);
}

Title=Name()+" ["+strInterval+"] "+ strWeekday + " " +Date()+ " Close: "
+WriteVal(C,format=1.2) +" "+WriteVal(per,format=1.0)+"-Per MA: "
+WriteVal(EMA1,format=1.2)+" " + WriteVal(per2,format=1.0)+"-Per MA: "
+WriteVal(EMA2,format=1.2) + " PR High: "+WriteVal(PRHi,format=1.2) + " PR Low: "
+WriteVal(PRLo,format=1.2);
```

Comment: Why don't you ask Amibroker support?

Answer (score 1):

this is the response i got in Amibroker forum.. thought i would share the answer..

This is both indicator and an exploration (however – this code is using very old approach, now it’s much more convenient to use PLOT or ADDCOLUMN functions instead of this obsolete coding style)

There are just some errors in the formula, as it uses assignment instead of equality check, so you need to replace:

HiLo=IIf(HLv=-1,

with

HiLo=IIf(HLv == -1,

the same with  - HiLoInvert=IIf(HLv=-1,

This is because == (double =) is an operator used for equality check.